# Pass variable in required file node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

I'm trying to pass variables to a file that I required in node.js so I can use them in that file.

```
var myname = "Adnan";
var incfile = require('./ex.js');
```

I'm wishing to be able to use `myname` variable in the ex.js file.

How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wishing to be able to use myname variable in the ex.js file.

I understand you want to do something like this so that `myname` is used by `ex.js` functions:

```
var myname = "Adnan";
var incfile = require('./ex.js')(myname);
```

So your `ex.js` should export a function:

```
var mynameInEx;
module.exports = function(myname) {
    mynameInEx = myname; // or whatever you want to do with myname here
    var incfile = 'returnedValue'+myname; // or whatever you want to return
    return incfile;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the answer I was looking for. :)